# Functional equation with the property $P(x+1)=P(x)+2x+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, functional-equations

> Find all polynomials with real-valued coefficients for which the following property $$P(x+1)=P(x)+2x+1$$ holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}.$

This seems to be a functional equation, so the initial approach would be to try some values. For $x=0$ we would have that $$P(1)=P(0)+1.$$

For $x=1$ $$P(2)=P(1)+3.$$

For $x=2$ $$P(3) = P(2)+5.$$

Now if I would know something about $P(0)$ that would seem to be helpful. If I assume that $P(0)=0$ I would get that

$$P(1)=1$$ $$P(2)=4$$ $$P(3)=9.$$

From here it would seem that $P(n)=n^2,$  however I’m not sure if I can make the assumption that $P(0)=0$ or can I?

Comment: How about $P(x)=x^2+c$?

Comment: Another option is to prove by induction that $P(n)-P(0)=n^2$ using the given equality. Then, $P(x)-x^2-P(0)$ will have ininitely many roots.

Comment: Does this thread answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843713?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve even more general problem:

**Problem.** For given polynomial $Q(x)$ find all polynomials $P(x)$ such that $P(x+1)-P(x)=Q(x)$.

**Solution**. Firstly, note that if $Q(x)\equiv 0$, then the only solution is $P(x)\equiv c$ for some real $c$. Now, suppose that $Q(x)=q_mx^m+\ldots+q_1x+q_0$, where $q_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and $q_m\neq 0$. If $P(x)=p_kx^k+\ldots+p_1x+p_0$ and $p_k\neq 0$, then we have
$$
P(x+1)-P(x)=Q(x),
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
p_k((x+1)^k-x^k)+\ldots+p_1((x+1)-x)=q_mx^m+\ldots+q_1x+q_0,
$$
or
$$
\binom{k}{k-1}p_{k}\cdot x^{k-1}+\left(\binom{k}{k-2}p_{k}+\binom{k-1}{k-2}p_{k-1}\right)\cdot x^{k-2}+\ldots+\left(\binom{k}{0}p_{k}+\binom{k-1}{0}p_{k-1}+\ldots+\binom{1}{0}p_{1}\right)\cdot 1=q_mx^m+\ldots+q_1x+q_0
$$
Since it holds for all $x$ we have $m=k-1$ and the following linear system:
$$
\begin{cases}
\binom{k}{k-1}p_{k}&=q_{k-1}
\\
\binom{k}{k-2}p_{k}+\binom{k-1}{k-2}p_{k-1}&=q_{k-2}
\\
\ldots
\\
\binom{k}{0}p_{k}+\binom{k-1}{0}p_{k-1}+\ldots+\binom{1}{0}p_{1}&=q_0
\end{cases}
$$
From this system we can find $p_{k},p_{k-1},\ldots,p_{1}$. Hence, the resulting polynomial $P(x)$ will be unique up to constant $p_0$ (and that's because $P(x+1)-P(x)=(P(x+1)+c)-(P(x)+c)$).

Applying this for your problem we obtain that $P(x)=x^2+c$.

Comment: Why is it $\binom{k}{1} p_k$ instead of $\binom{k}{0} p_k$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $P$ be a solution, and let $Q(x)=P(x)-x^2$. Then $Q(x+1)=Q(x)$. Thus, $Q(x)-Q(0)$ is zero at all integer values of $x$. A nonzero polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots, hence $Q(x)-Q(0)=0$ identically, and $P(x)=x^2+P(0)$.

Answer (score 2):

Get the second derivative from the both side of the equation. You will get:

$$
P'(x+1) - P'(x) = 2 \Rightarrow P''(x+1) = P''(x) 
$$

It means the second derivative is constant. Hence, $P''(x) = c$ and it means $P(x)$ is in the form of $c x^2 + bx + a$. Now we have:

$$
c(x+1)^2 + b(x+1) + a - cx^2-bx - a = 2x + 1 \Rightarrow c(2x+1)+b = 2x+1 
\Rightarrow c = 1, b = 0
$$

Therefore, $P(x) = x^2 + a$ ($a$ can be any value in $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 1):

Big hint: suppose $P(0)=c$ and work towards proving $P(x)=x^2+c$

Solution:
$$P(x+1)=P(x)+2x+1$$
Well our initial assumption from the looks of it that $P(x)=x^2+c$, but we'll work towards proving it's the only solution. First of all:
$$P(x+1)-P(x)=2x+1$$
because $P$ is a polynomial, this directly means that $P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, because of the well known **method of differences** (check it on brilliant wiki). It means that the second difference for the values of the polynomial is constant. (one can also know that by differentiating) So
$$a((x+1)^2-x^2)+b((x+1)-x)=2x+1$$
$$\iff 2ax+a+b=2x+1$$
Thus, by equating coefficients, $a=1$ and $b=0$
so
$$P(x)=x^2+c$$
for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\deg P=n$. Then we can write
$$P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kx^k.$$
From the functional equation,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k(x+1)^k=1+2x+\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kx^k.$$
Using the property of binomial coefficients $$m>n\Rightarrow {n\choose m}=0,\tag{1}$$
we have $$P(x+1)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k\sum_{j=0}^{n}{k\choose j}x^j=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\alpha_jx^j,$$
where $$\alpha_j=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k\choose j}a_k.\tag{2}$$
Comparing coefficients, we have that 
$$\begin{align}
\alpha_0&=1+a_0,\\
\alpha_1&=2+a_1,\\
\alpha_j&=a_j\qquad j\ge 2.
\end{align}$$
Then from $(2)$, we have 
$${0\choose 2}a_0+{1\choose 2}a_1+{2\choose 2}a_2+{3\choose 2}a_3+...+{n\choose 2}a_n=a_2.\tag{3}$$
We have that $(3)$ implies $a_j=0$ for all $j\ge 3$, because ${0\choose 2}={1\choose 2}=0$ from $(1)$. Therefore, $\deg P=2$ and we have 
$$\alpha_j=\sum_{k=0}^{2}{k\choose j}a_k.$$
Thus 
$$\begin{align}
1+a_0=&\alpha_0=a_0+a_1+a_2\\
2+a_1=&\alpha_1=a_1+2a_2.
\end{align}$$
Thus we are left with the system of equations
$$\begin{align}
1=&a_1+a_2\\
2=&2a_2,
\end{align}$$
which has the solution $(a_0,a_1,a_2)=(a_0,0,1)$, meaning that $a_0$ can be any constant. Thus we have
$$P(x)=x^2+a_0$$
for any $a_0\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the polynomial $P$ is of degree $n$, and write $P(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots$ (i.e., not bothering to write down more than the first two terms). Then

$$P(x+1)=a_0(x+1)^n+a_1(x+1)^{n-1}+\cdots=a_0x^n+(na_0+a_1)x^{n-1}+\cdots$$

so $P(x+1)-P(x)=na_0x^{n-1}+\cdots$. Now if $P(x+1)-P(x)=2x+1$, we must have $n-1=1$ and $na_0=2$, which is to say $n=2$ and $a_0=1$.

At this point we write  $P(x)=x^2+bx+c$ and see that

$$P(x+1)=(x^2+2x+1)+b(x+1)+c=(x^2+bx+c)+(2x+1)+b$$

It follows that $P(x+1)=P(x)+2x+1$ holds if and only if $b=0$. So $P(x)=x^2+c$